# How to filter by date range in django-rest?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'd like to filter my data by date range typed in browser, all other filtering are working.

**views.py**

```
class BookView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializers
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['title', 'language', 'authors', 'date']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new filter:

```
class StatementItemFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    date_between = filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name="MODEL_FIELD_NAME", label="Date (Between)")

    class Meta:
        model = StatementItem
        fields = [
            ...
            "date_between"
        ]
```

and use in your viewset

```
class MODELItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = StatementItemFilter
    ...
```

Move your list `['title', 'language', 'authors', 'date']` to your new filterset class